# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/designea/public_html/blog/blog_end/inc/comments.inc.php on line 1

Tags: php

Im getting this error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/designea/public_html/blog/blog_end/inc/comments.inc.php on line 1" can somebody help me..here's my code

```
<?php 
function get_gravatar( $email = $_POST['email1'], $s = 50, $d = 'mm', $r = 'g', $img = false, $atts = array() ) {
        $url = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/';
        $url .= md5( strtolower( trim( $email ) ) );
        $url .= "?s=$s&d=$d&r=$r";
        if ( $img ) {
            $url = '<img src="' . $url . '"';
            foreach ( $atts as $key => $val )
                $url .= ' ' . $key . '="' . $val . '"';
            $url .= ' />';
        }
        return $url;
    }
?>
```

Comment: `$email = $_POST['email1']` in an argument list? I can't imagine that's legal to do.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot have a default argument value that is not a literal, so this is illegal:

```
$email = $_POST['email1']
```

A typical workaround for this is to write

```
function get_gravatar( $email = null ) {
    if ($email === null) {
        $email = $_POST['email1'];
    }
}
```

However, coupling the behavior of your function to `$_POST` like this is best avoided. In your shoes I would remove the default value entirely.